# How to set the timezone of the database

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to set the timezone of database in gorm.
I set my database timezone to UTC, in pgadmin I added a parameter with timezone and value UTC.
Everything is working fine, the data is saved in UTC, is retrieved in UTC, but when I save a new struct to database, for example `User`, after save if verify the `User.created_at` is not in UTC timezone, is in my local timezone.
I want to make this working, because I create a response with the created `User` to the ongoing request.

Update:
My code:

```
type Customer struct {
    ID          uuid.UUID  `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;index;" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time  `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time  `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt   *time.Time `json:"deleted_at,omitempty"`
 }
```

Comment: How is it being set? Are you passing it from Go or is it set by Postgres on insert?

Comment: I am not passing it, i let gorm to deal with it

Comment: What is the exact type of that column?

Comment: @zerkms I updated my question and added my code

Comment: @jalanga in postgresql, what is the type of the column?

Comment: @zerkms timestamp with timezone

Comment: Then the timezone of the value is the timezone that the client set to it explicitly, postgresql does not convert it but accepts as is.

Comment: @zerkms but why in pgadmin I see it in UTC, when I retrieve is in UTC but when I save the user, created_at is in GMT+

Comment: Because a client is free to convert it to whatever they want. If you want to store something in UTC you should do that when you store a record. But anyway, what is the point to store it in UTC only?

Comment: Project convention, we work just with UTC and frontend converts to the timezone of the client

Comment: @jalanga so how storing in any other arbitrary timezone would prevent you from doing the same? In postgresql a client always decides in what timezone you output the value. Unless you check it explicitly you won't even know in what timezone it's stored at the moment

Comment: Every filtering, and sorting is made in UTC.

Comment: Sure, you must specify timezone when you connect and/or in every query **explicitly**, it does not matter in what timezone the value is stored, it changes nothing at all. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html --- set timezone in the connection string. If you set it to `UTC` then all predicates would be run against UTC (unless you specify otherwise explicitly), no matter in what tz the values were originally stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try callback in gorm. Like this

```
// updateTimeStampForCreateCallback will set `CreatedAt`, `UpdatedAt` when creating
func updateTimeStampForCreateCallback(scope *gorm.Scope) {
    if !scope.HasError() {
        now := time.Now().UTC()

        if createdAtField, ok := scope.FieldByName("CreatedAt"); ok {
            if createdAtField.IsBlank {
                createdAtField.Set(now)
            }
        }

        if updatedAtField, ok := scope.FieldByName("UpdatedAt"); ok {
            if updatedAtField.IsBlank {
                updatedAtField.Set(now)
            }
        }
    }
}

// updateTimeStampForUpdateCallback will set `UpdatedAt` when updating
func updateTimeStampForUpdateCallback(scope *gorm.Scope) {
    if _, ok := scope.Get("gorm:update_column"); !ok {
        scope.SetColumn("UpdatedAt", time.Now().UTC())
    }
}
```

Then register in db.Callback()

```
db.Callback().Create().Replace("gorm:update_time_stamp", updateTimeStampForCreateCallback)
db.Callback().Update().Replace("gorm:update_time_stamp", updateTimeStampForUpdateCallback)
```